# Revert some of commits and separating them into new branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-revert

Suppose that there is commits A, B, C and D and they're all in master branch, so the history looks like this.

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> HEAD.
```

C and D brings some features that are not quite tested, and you need to separate them into new branch (which you should've done in the first place), test them, etc. and then merge back.

So how do i revert master to commit B and separate C and D into new branch so the branch tree looks like this?

```
A -> B -> master's HEAD.
      \-> C -> D -> new branch's HEAD.
```

Comment: `git checkout -b new-branch && git checkout - && git reset HEAD~2 --hard`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe and how do i make this changes on remote?

Comment: Same way you get any other changes to the remote: push them. Note that you'll have to force push to master, which is... not ideal. If there are other people working from that branch you may cause problems.

Comment: Yeah... but still, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways. You want a new branch label on `D` and the master branch label on `B`.  There's the way in comments, or this slightly-shorter way:

```
git branch newbranch
git reset --hard @~2
```

or this way that leaves you on the new branch, so there's less work tree churn if that's where you're working from:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
git branch -f master @~2
```

---

one note: there's only one `HEAD`, it is the parent `git commit` will use. As a matter of clarity, branches have tips. `HEAD` is usually attached to (i.e. a symbolic link to) whatever you last checked out, committed, or reset to, so when you check out a branch, git sets `HEAD` to be a symbolic ref, an alias, for that branch tip.